# ExtJS Support for Browser Detection

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to detect browser type so that I can log browser type in case of an error in my ExtJS application.  I know there are several JavaScript libraries that can detect browser type, but if I deploy these with my code I will have to update the libraries regularly.

My question is: does ExtJS do a good job keeping their browser detection functionality up-to-date?  I am using ExtJS 4.2.

Comment: For additional info, I have investigated the "how", just curious if it is wise to trust ExtJS 4.2 browser detection.  Also, I am adding additional functionality to an existing app and do not have the option to update to ExtJS 5 or 6.

Answer (score 1):

> does ExtJS do a good job keeping their browser detection functionality
>   up-to-date? I am using ExtJS 4.2.

It does. Version 4.2 is not quite up-to-date though. Use the latest Ext JS if it is crucial to you to have browser detection functionality up-to-date.

In 4.2, the [Ext](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext-property-browser) singleton has a range of properties telling about the browser. Starting from version 5 there is a dedicated [Ext.browser](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.browser) singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for different browsers in Extjs 4.2 version.

- IE DETECTION WITH EXTJS

  Ext.isIE6, Ext.isIE7
- DETECTING FIREFOX WITH EXTJS

  if (Ext.isFF5) {
     // Firefox 5
  }
  // or in general you can use

  if (Ext.isGecko) {
     // Firefox or Mozilla
  }
- DETECTING CHROME WITH EXTJS 4

  if (Ext.isChrome) {
     // Chrome
  }
- DETECTING SAFARI WITH EXT JS 4

  // In general without version
  if (Ext.isSafari) {
     // Safari
  }

  if (Ext.isSafari5_0) {
     // Safari 5.0.x
  }

Source : http://jaspreetchahal.org/extjs-4-detect-browser/